# Impossible to use Array.toString() after suscribe and push

Tags: arrays, angular, string, type-conversion

Here's a problematic piece of code :

```
const arr1 = new Array;

this.formData.players.split(',').forEach((id) => {
  this.userService.getUser(Number(id)).subscribe((user: User) => {
    arr1.push(user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname);
  });
});

console.log(arr1);
console.log('Players: ' + arr1.join(', '));

/* - - - - - */

const arr2 = new Array;

arr2.push('orange');
arr2.push('mango');
arr2.push('banana');
arr2.push('sugar');

console.log(arr2);
console.log('Test: ' + arr.join(', '));
```

The first part get user's identity from a Spring database. The second one is for testing.

My log :

```
[]
  0: "John Doe"
  1: "Jane Doe"
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)

Players:

(4) ["orange", "mango", "banana", "sugar"]
  0: "orange"
  1: "mango"
  2: "banana"
  3: "sugar"
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array(0)

Test: orange, mango, banana, sugar
```

I don't understand why my first piece of code refuses to display:

```
Players: John Doe, Jane Doe
```

Comment: are you getting some error on console or just nothing for that exact line??

Comment: These exact lines, no error neither in the angular terminal nor in the chrome console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for that is because your `console.log` function will be called before all subscribes will be finished.

```
You can try to use something like https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/mergeall instead.

from(this.formData.players.split(',')).pipe(
  map(id => this.userService.getUser(Number(id)).pipe(tap(user: User) => {
    arr1.push(user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname);
  })),
  mergeAll()
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(arr1);
  console.log('Players: ' + arr1.join(', '));
});
```

Comment: Thanks !!! It almost works. When I replace of(this.formData.players.split(',')) by of(2, 1) it work. Seems that the split command gives me an array of strings and the of cannot understand it as a row of elements. I hope I can make myself understood.

Comment: It worked !!!! I just had to write from(this.assisesData.medecins.split(',')) instead of 'of'. Thanks very much, Kateryna!

Comment: If you can explain to me I would be very grateful, I try to learn ;)

Comment: @Smarties yes! Your code `this.userService.getUser(Number(id)).subscribe` is running asynchronously. This means that your synchronous code ( like `console.log` in the same scope ) will be executed first. So, you have to make sure that your console.log will be called AFTER all the async calls. That's why I have placed it in subscription section. P.S. You can upvote my answer if it helped you a bit

Comment: Solved! Thanks to you. Thanks again